Add an event listener for when an external app is opened in the page where my content script is being ran
I am creating a browser extension, and I want to open a React dialog/modal to the user when joining a Zoom meeting.
Ideally I want to pause the automatic opening of the Zoom application while the user doesn't interact with the dialog, and when it does, if the interaction is positive (clicks the 'yes' button) resume the opening of the Zoom application. If negative, abort the opening.
I am also happy with a solution that shows the dialog without caring if the zoom app is opened or not.
I've tried doing this, but no success. The script is simply not ran.
Here is my manifest.json (some parts were omitted)
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "https://*zoom.us/*",
    "https://zoom.us/*"
  ], 
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.zoom.us/*", "https://zoom.us/*"],
      "js": ["js/contentScript.bundle.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]

contentScript.tsx
console.log('ContentScript running...');

// HTML injection
const app = document.createElement('div');
app.id = 'react-root';
document.querySelector('body')?.prepend(app);

ReactDOM.render(<Dialog />, document.getElementById('react-root'));

console log
Launched external handler for 'zoommtg://zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=SOME_NUMBER&pwd=SOME_PWD&confid=SOME_CONFID&browser=chrome'.

(no sign of ContentScript running...)
I've also tried changing the run_at in the manifest.json to "document_start" but then I get the following error:
Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.


Assuming the tab you're looking at actually matches zoom.us pattern, you need to reload it after reloading or installing the extension in order to run the content script.

@wOxxOm yes, i am doing that.

If it runs at document_start then it must also run without it, otherwise it would be a bug in the browser. Anyway, you can use document_start and MutationObserver to wait for the container.

@wOxxOm Yeah that is what I thought, but no, it doesn't run! Somehow Zoom cancels any content-script with run_at document_end. I've also tried to listen to event DOMContentLoaded with document_start and also doesn't run - i guess it is the same.

@wOxxOm can you expand on "... MutationObserver to wait for the container."
